# issues w/ centering google map in bootstrap3 modal... keeps changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

Hi and thanks for your help. I have a bootstrap 3 page that I put a google map into a modal. After MUCH tweaking and research, reading I was able to get the map to show, correctly in desktop and mobile formats (map fill the modal no grey, not break out of modal in responsive etc.) The last issue is that now I find the center marker does not center inside the frame after render all the time. That is to say SOMETIMES after a page reload the map will appear correctly, sometimes, mostly not. This is in Chrome, Firefox, Mozilla and Opera test browsers. Hours and hours spent on this help please.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<!-- Google Map In Modal -->
            <!-- Button to trigger modal -->
            <p><a href="#mapmodals" data-toggle="modal" role="button" data-target="#mapModal" class="btn btn-primary"><b>Map to Satori Spa</b></a></p>  

            <!-- MAPS -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="mapModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="#mapModal" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg"">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:#000;">Satori Spa Massage - Encino Ca.</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="map-container"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
              </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

JS at bottom of page

```
    <!-- Google Map In Modal -->
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
            var var_map;
            var var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(34.158540,-118.493270);

     function map_init() {          

            var var_mapoptions = {  
          center: new google.maps.LatLng( 34.158540, -118.493270 ),
              zoom: 11,
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
              mapTypeControl: true,
              panControl:false,
              rotateControl:false,
              streetViewControl: true,
            };

            var_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
                var_mapoptions);

          var contentString = 
                '<div id="mapInfo">'+
                '<p style=" font-size:12px; line-height:14px; color:#000;"><strong>Satori Spa Massage</strong><br>'+
                '16545 Ventura Blvd Suite 27<br>' +
                'Encino, California,<br>91436 USA<br>'+
                'P: (818) 907-9967</p>'+
                '<a href="http://www.satorispamassage.com" target="_blank">Plan your visit</a>'+
                '</div>';

          var var_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString
          });

          var var_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: var_location = new google.maps.LatLng(34.158540,-118.493270),
            map: var_map,
            title:"Click for information about the Satori Spa Massage in Encino",
                  maxWidth: 200,
                  maxHeight: 200
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(var_marker, 'click', function() {
             var_infowindow.open(var_map,var_marker);
          });
      }

          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map_init);

      //start of modal google map
      $('#mapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
          google.maps.event.trigger(var_map, "resize");
          map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(34.158540, -118.493270));
      initialize();
          });
</script>
```

Live page is here @ satorispamassage.com
Thanks again and Any help appreciated.

Comment: Check also that you have here: <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg""> two quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue is that  you call the method setCenter of `map` , but the name of the variable is `var_map`.

Another issue: it may happen that someone opens the modal before the map has been created, test the variable before you access it:

```
  //start of modal google map
  $('#mapModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {

    //test if the map already has been created
    if(var_map){
      google.maps.event.trigger(var_map, "resize");
      var_map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(34.158540, -118.493270));
    }
  });
```

(Also removed the call of `initialize`, there is no such function)

Comment: Thank you dbd and Dr.Molle for the help and educating me. Both answers are accurate and the code now works across all browsers  (tested in 4) and also renders correctly in smart phone. Thank you both again.